# Issue installing `flutter_twitter_login` and `TwitterKit` with Flutter

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

I'm trying to build an app made in Flutter onto iOS right now.  However, I'm getting issues including all the dependencies (shown below).  When I build the app for the first time, it runs `pod install` and everything goes fine until it starts running pre install hooks, where I get a big block of error messages (below).  What I can tell from this is I have some sort of issue with `flutter_twitter_login` (one of the error messages says something about twitter), and that there's an issue with my podfile (the error message asks me to call out a minimum version of iOS).  Additionally, if I try to run it again (changing the podfile so it doesn't complain about the minimum version thing), it gives me an error saying it can't find `<TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h>` (the full error message below).

I tried to replicate this by building the [example program](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_twitter_login#-example-tab-) for `flutter_twitter_login`, and it was able to build find with the exact same `pubspec.yaml`.  I also noticed that in `/path/to/project/ios/Pods/TwitterKit/iOS/TwitterKit.framework/Headers/`, there is no `TwitterKit.h` just like the error says, but in the project that I made to replicate the error there is.

So I think there's something bad going on with how cocoapods is installing TwitterKit, and the fact that I'm getting complaints about not calling out a minimum iOS version in the auto-generated podfile suggests that there's something funny with how that's being made.  However, I'm not really sure how to proceed with debugging this since the problem evidently isn't with `pubspec.yaml`, since the file that I have can successfully build other projects, and my understanding is that the podfile comes directly from `pubspec.yaml`.

*Code snippets and error messages*

I have this in `pubspec.yaml` (everything other than this is from the template):

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.2.5
  firebase_analytics: ^1.0.4
  http: "^0.11.3+17"
  firebase_auth: 0.6.2+1
  google_sign_in: ^3.2.1
  flutter_twitter_login: "^1.1.0"
  fluttertoast: ^2.0.7
  flutter_svg: ^0.6.1+1
```

Big block of error messages while cocoapods is running pre install hooks:

```
      - Running pre install hooks
    [!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/path/to/project/ios/Pods/TwitterKit/iOS/TwitterKit.framework)

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:73:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:73:in `block in verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:70:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:70:in `verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:36:in `validate!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:415:in `validate_targets'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:118:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:41:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.5.3/libexec/bin/pod:22:in `load'
    /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.5.3/libexec/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

    [!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

Can't find `TwitterKit.h`:

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /path/to/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_twitter_login-1.1.0/ios/Classes/TwitterLoginPlugin.m:2:9: fatal error: 'TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h' file not found
    #import <TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: I haven't been able to work on this since I posted.  The next thing I was going to try is rebuilding the app piece by piece in a new project to try to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar Problem I find the answer here
[enter link description here](https://github.com/roughike/flutter_twitter_login/issues/12)

So the important part is

```
change #import <TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h> to #import <TwitterKit/TWTRKit.h>
in file TwitterLoginPlugin.m
```

After
go to

```
flutter_twitter_login.podspec
```

and add these 2 frameworks

```
TwitterKit.framework,TwitterCore.framework
```

Like in the photo
[image]

After that run pod install again

with my problems works hope could help

Answer (score 0):

I found that I required Xcode to find the file (was using Android Studio for development) that requires the changes for this to work. What I did was:

1. Open your project in Xcode
2. Search for TwitterLoginPlugin.m
3. Find at the top of the file the imports and replace the

   #import <TwitterKit/TwitterKit.h>

with

```
#import <TwitterKit/TWTRKit.h>
```

This allowed my app to run but when the login button is pressed (TwitterLoginPlugin is called) the program crashes. This happens of course only on iOS as mentioned by many other posts on this matter. [An issue was posted on their GitHub page about this](https://github.com/roughike/flutter_twitter_login/issues/12). That is where I found my answer and @Romy supports this link as well from the other answers. Another valuable resource I am exploring currently to resolve this issue is [the TwitterKit GitHub Wiki](https://github.com/twitter-archive/twitter-kit-ios/wiki/Installation).